# How does my plugin appear under the WYSIWYG Editor in "Create new article"-Screen

Tags: wordpress

I have written a Wordpress Plugin and now I want, that the Plugin appears (HTML Form) in the "Create New Article"-Screen unter the WYSIWYG Editor (after installation and activation). How can this be done. In the Codex and other sources I haven't found anything related to that problem.

BR & Thanks in advance,
mybecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of this feature in wordpress [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)

There is every thing available.you want!

Comment: No I'm not aware of this feature, I didn't find it, cause I don't know after what I needed to look :-) Thanks thats it!

Comment: @mybecks:Ok no problem.there is all example you got add those function in your plugin file.i think you got the answer